# What's the easiest way to switch a Java program from UDP to TCP?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, udp

I've been given a Java application that uses the `java.net.DatagramSocket` class, and it uses UDP. I need to switch this to TCP, is there a simple way to do this or do I need to rewrite the whole application? I'm sorry if this is a noobish question, but I'm just starting with networking.

Comment: UDP and TCP operate on very different principle. For the most part you can (inefficiently) wrap up and transport UDP packets via TCP easily enough, though you probably want to do it at a slightly higher level to track the connections. Still, I have to ask why you're doing this to begin with?

Comment: I am facing similar issue trying to implement a P2P network. FIrst, I am connecting two clients with DatagramSocket and then I want to wrap that socket to transmit data more reliably.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you will have to change your code, Datagram sockets cannot be used for TCP as both are completely different. TCP is reliable transfer protocol unlike UDP and generally a handshake is thus necessary.

For TCP Server

```
  ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789) 
  Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
  BufferedReader inFromClient =
  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
  DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
  clientmsg = inFromClient.readLine();
  System.out.println("Received: " + clientmsg);
```

Comment: This does not seem to be what the original question is about.